# Using Sound files C# - modifying tempo

Tags: c#, audio, tempo

Does anyone have any idea how to modify the sound speed and play a sound file faster/slower than the original in C#?

At the moment I am using `.wav` files, I have searched a lot and found that `SoundPlayer` and `AudioVideoPlayback` are the only two options to play sound, but none of them contain any special method to increase or decrease the sound speed with which to play with.

I am building a piano application which lets user modify the tempo, this is the situation I am in at the moment. I hope a few musical programmers can help me! Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question was asked earlier:

[C# Audio Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466458/c-sharp-audio-library)

One of the answers there suggested the following tool which might be helpful to you:

http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you  very much! I will check both links out immediately.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a time-stretch audio library, which changes the playback speed but not the pitch -- with almost no artefacts.

A few excellent timestretch libraries available:

dirac: http://www.dspdimension.com/ (best)

rubberband: http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/