# C# Audio library that allows me to redistribute

Tags: c#, audio

I am making a game library in C# and I need a free audio library that enable me to do these things.

- Play sounds simultaneously.
- Play background MIDI music.
- Play these formats.

  - WAV
  - AIFF
  - MIDI
  - AU
- Allow me to redistribute the library with my engine ( I'll use only binaries )
- Allow selling of games made using it.

Are there any c# libraries which allow me to do these things?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466458/c-sharp-audio-library

Comment: Are you sure you need right these file formats? They are 20 years old and obsolete.

Comment: I was just porting my java library to C# and I know modifying them because these are the only formats supported by java