# How can I autoplay C# Winform using SoundPlayer for music?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

How can I make it so that when the current song stops playing the next song will play? The app is working 100% with the play, pause, and skip to control the music that's an embedded resource also exported with Fody for an exe file. I only have to get the music to play automatically when the current song is finished. The files are .wav also.

My `SoundPlayerManager.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Resources;

public class SoundPlayerManager
{
    private static SoundPlayerManager instance;
    private int currentSoundPlayerIndex = 0;
    private List<SoundPlayer> soundPlayers = new List<SoundPlayer>();
    public event EventHandler PlayRandomSongEvent;

    private SoundPlayerManager()
    {
        InitializeSoundPlayers();
    }

    public static SoundPlayerManager GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new SoundPlayerManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private void InitializeSoundPlayers()
    {
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.all_girls_are_the_same));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.armed_and_dangerous));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.all_girls_are_the_same));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.armed_and_dangerous));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.bad_boy));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.bandit_og));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.bottle));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.coconut_mall));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.final_battle));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.flower_garden));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.glock_handler));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.gopro));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.gourmet_race));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.iron_on_me));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.jeffrey));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.nobody));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.nuketown));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.racks_in));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.racks_out));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.soda_pop));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.spanglish));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.stumblin));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.toxic_humans));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.wii_shop));
        // Add more sound files as needed
    }

    private void NextSong(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentSoundPlayerIndex = (currentSoundPlayerIndex + 1) % soundPlayers.Count;
        soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Play();
    }

    public void PlayRandomSong()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.Next(0, soundPlayers.Count);
        soundPlayers[index].Play();
    }


    public void PauseCurrentSong()
    {
        soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Stop();
    }

    public void SkipToNextSong()
    {
        currentSoundPlayerIndex = (currentSoundPlayerIndex + 1) % soundPlayers.Count;
        soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Play();
    }
}
```

`Main.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Media;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static Siticone.Desktop.UI.WinForms.Suite.Descriptions;
using System.Resources;
using DevExpress.XtraWaitForm;

namespace KeyAuth
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private SoundPlayerManager soundPlayerManager;

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            soundPlayerManager = SoundPlayerManager.GetInstance();
        } // LOADING MAIN

        private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Turn me up. A LOT!", "999");
            soundPlayerManager.PlayRandomSong();
        } // PLAY BUTTON

        private void pauseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soundPlayerManager.PauseCurrentSong();
        } // PAUSE BUTTON

        private void skipButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soundPlayerManager.SkipToNextSong();
        } // Skip button click event handler
    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed some of the Main.cs code that wasn't needed for the quesiton.

Comment: A way could be to create a timer with an interval of the duration of the sound but as you can see from those questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477174/c-sharp-get-time-from-soundplayer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603295/playing-sounds-accessing-length-and-position

it seems like the SoundPlayer class don't have this type of information.

Comment: Trick it by adding two soundPlayerManagers and queue the next song (precalculated random) and queue the alternate soundPlayerManager. Then simply swap the z-order, play the 2nd and queue up the first soundPlayerManager to the next song again.

Answer (score 0):

Define variable currentSongIndex =0 and override
`soundPlayer.SoundLocationChanged += SoundPlayer_SoundLocationChanged;`
like

```
    private void SoundPlayer_SoundLocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentSongIndex++;
        PlayCurrentSong();
    }

    private void PlayCurrentSong()
    {
        if (currentSongIndex < songPaths.Length)
        {
            string currentSongPath = songPaths[currentSongIndex];
            soundPlayer.SoundLocation = currentSongPath;
            soundPlayer.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All songs have been played.");
            // Handle end of playlist or loop to the beginning
            currentSongIndex = 0;
            PlayCurrentSong();
        }
    }
```

Please do not forget to call PlayCurrentSong(); in Initialize or Load of Form