# Playing chords as simultaneous sounds

Tags: c#, audio, simultaneous, music-notation

I want to build a musical Ear Training program. I have samples of piano notes on mp3 or wav files, and i want to play them simultaneously to build musical chords.

What will be the easiest or the most successful way of playing sounds together?

Thanks :-)

Comment: _What have you tried so far to solve this problem?_ Show your effort first.. Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Have a look at this interesting discussion - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d9391ced-ad5d-42dd-9025-f387828c0ca8/

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Thanks, but i need to play chords from audio files, not displaying notes (yet)...

Comment: @SonerGönül I have searched how to play sounds simultaneously, and found few solutions: A library called NAUDIO for C#, playing the sounds in Media player. I just wanted to know what will be the best practice to such a project.

Comment: Looks like you have to use the Managed DirectX SDK - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/abc86695-20c6-4dcd-82cb-544a9111cd11

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of things you could call the [SDL_mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) library. It's not C#, but [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cs-sdl/index.php?title=Audio) you can see it interfaced by C# in a gaming library.

You can have multiple channels, each one playing a different sound.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466458/c-sharp-audio-library) for popular C# audio libraries and refer to their documentations on how to achieve simultaneous playback (e.g. [BASS.NET](http://bass.radio42.com/help/Index.html), [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation) etc.).