# Play sound on a recording device in C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio

In our solution we need to play sound on one of the recording devices.
For this purpose we are using VAC (Virtual Audio Cable), but we have a problem that it creates noise in the output.

Is it possible to play audio to recording device in C#?

Is there some existing library for that or virtual audio driver is required?

Comment: Is it a physical recording device?

Comment: Sound is played on VM, so it could be virtual recording device.

Answer (score 0):

There are useful 3rd-party-tools & APIs in a question was asked earlier:[C# Audio Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466458/c-sharp-audio-library).
I hope you find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

We used NAudio library to play sound on a specific playback device.

By default VAC is duplicating audio from playback device to recording device, so by playing it on virtual device it's also played on recording device.